# How to select data with linq after filter parameters are determined

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a report in which the user can select different filters to apply to a dataset.

At design time, I don't know what filters the user will apply, so I grab the whole dataset.

For instance, if the user wants to see contacts that live in Chicago, I first grab all contacts...

```
IList<contact> contacts = db.contacts.ToList();
```

then I check the form collection for filters and apply them...

```
contacts = contacts.Where(t => t.state == form["state"]).ToList();
```

The issue is that getting all contacts to filter down from is resource intensive. Is there a way to wait to retrieve the contacts from the db until I have all the parameters for the query?

I realize I'm doing this wrong, but I need to know the correct way to approach this.

Comment: "if the user wants to see contacts that live in Chicago, I first grab all contacts.." **Why??**. Execute your query with filter at that time, instead of getting all the records and then applying filter.

Comment: IF you didn't have the `ToList` call on the first line then that would do what you want. It would then use the `Queryable` version of Where and send your where predicate up to the query provider (if it is able to translate it properly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't do the first call to `ToList()`. This pulls down all the data into memory. While you haven't done this, the data is in the form of an `IEnumerable`. This uses 'lazy evaluation' which means that the items to be enumerated aren't actually produced until they are requested. In the case of Linq To SQL, the database query won't be run until you do the second call to `ToList()`.

An `IEnumerable` is not really a container, rather it's an object, containing a piece of code that knows how to get the next element in a sequence. This piece of code could be various things - it could be reading from an actual container, generating each value on-the-fly, or getting the values from somewhere else, like a database. A list however, **is** a container. When you call `ToList`, the next item is repeatedly extracted from the `IEnumerable` and placed in a `List`. At this point you have exactly a collection of objects in memory. You often call `ToList` when you want to stop having a nebulous 'thing' which gets values from *somewhere* and have an actual container full of actual elements. For example, an `IEnumerable` might not give you the same objects each time you use it. Once you have them in a `List` you know that they can't change. In your case you *want* to stay with that nebulous thing until you have decided exactly what you are going to have to ask the database for.

The way this works is fundamental to LINQ, and also is the main reason that Linq To SQL is so nice. I highly recommend that you read something about how Linq works, and also play around with List and IEnumerable a little bit. [C# legend Jon Skeet's blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/LINQ/default.aspx) has loads of discussion of this, including an example reimplementation of much of Linq so you can see how it might work. If you read all of it you will be a Linq expert (and it will also be very late), but [this is an introduction to how laziness works](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/03/25/just-how-lazy-are-you.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Don't call `ToList()`.

You're getting an `IEnumerable` back from EF. Use the lazy evaluation to your advantage - it's especially useful with large datasets, as every call to `.ToList()` fills the memory with the list.